# install .rpm or .msi file through python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rpm

I'm a newbie to python. I have a python script to download a rpm file from S3 bucket.

```
import platform
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'tempdownload'
KEY = 'temp.rpm' # packaged using golang

platformName = platform.system()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

print(platformName)

if platformName == 'Linux':
    try:
        bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
        bucket.download_file(KEY, 'temp.rpm')
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print("The object does not exist.")
        else:
            raise
else:
    print("not valid operating system")
```

I want to add a script in the same file to install the downloaded rpm file or msi package for windows. I tried searching online but didn't get any information. Would appreciate if anyone provide some pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: `import subprocess; subprocess.check_call(['rpm', '-U', FILENAME])`. If the bucket is public, you can specify the http URL directly to RPM without downloading it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call system command - `rpm -Ivh yourpackage.rpm`

```
import subprocess
package_path = '/home/mypackage.rpm'
command = ['rpm', '-Ivh', package_path]
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
p.wait()
if p.returncode == 0:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

Comment: Thanks @szymon! I will try it out. I was wondering how do we install if it is an windows msi package?

Comment: You just need to replace the command with `['msiexec', '/i', package_path, 'quiet', 'qn'`

Comment: I am seeing this error with exact same script given in answer: Executing command "['/bin/rpm', '--ivh ', '/opt/starter/app_dist/filename.noarch.rpm']"
rpm: --ivh : unknown option
Something went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can install it directly from Python using rpm bindings. See: https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch16s06.html

But rather, you should not call rpm directly, but rather call Yum or DNF or its python bindings.