# How to install Java manually using .rpm files on cloud (streamlit) using python script?

Tags: python, java, pyspark, streamlit

I am new to `unix` & `cloud` not from IT background and not sure how to install `Java` manually on cloud. I am trying to install Java on `streamlit` to be able to use `Pyspark`.

I have tried below code but not sure how to **install** using `downloaded` `.rpm` file with `python`.

[App_link](https://os-explore.streamlit.app/)

[Github_link](https://github.com/johnsnow09/os_explore/blob/main/app.py)

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

import os
import sys
import wget
# import tarfile
import platform
```

**1. Download Java**

```
# for linux from: https://crunchify.com/where-is-java-installed-on-my-mac-osx-system/
f = wget.download("https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11.0.2+9/f51449fcd52f4d52b93a989c5c56ed3c/jdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.rpm")

st.write(" Java Downloaded")
```

> Java Downloaded

**2. Cross check Platform**

```
st.write("Checking platform: ",platform.system())
```

> Checking platform: Linux

**3. Checking Directories & files**

```
st.write("Current Directory: ",os.getcwd())
st.write("Directory list: ",os.listdir())
```

> Current Directory: /mount/src/os_explore

Directory list:

> [ 0:"requirements.txt" 1:"app.py" 2:"README.md" 3:".git"
> 4:"jdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.rpm" 5:"packages.txt" 6:".streamlit" ]

**4. Installing using .rpm file**

```
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484772/install-rpm-or-msi-file-through-python-script
import rpm
import subprocess
package_path = '/mount/src/os_explore/jdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.rpm'
# command = ['rpm', '-Ivh', package_path]
command = ['rpm', '-ivh', package_path]
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
p.wait()
if p.returncode == 0:
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

Getting Errors from here onwards

[image]

**Error in text:**

> ImportError: Failed to import system RPM module. Make sure RPM Python
> bindings are installed on your system.
>
> 2023-09-30 05:04:01.256 Uncaught app exception
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rpm/**init**.py",
> line 102, in
>
> ```
> _shim_module_initializing_
> ```
>
> NameError: name '*shim_module_initializing*' is not defined
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py",
> line 565, in _run_script
>
> ```
> exec(code, module.__dict__)
> ```
>
> File "/mount/src/os_explore/app.py", line 61, in
>
> ```
> import rpm
> ```
>
> File
> "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rpm/**init**.py",
> line 105, in
>
> ```
> initialize()
> ```
>
> File
> "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rpm/**init**.py",
> line 94, in initialize
>
> ```
> raise ImportError(
> ```
>
> ImportError: Failed to import system RPM module. Make sure RPM Python
> bindings are installed on your system.

**I would really Appreciate help here** as I am stuck on installing Java from days and literally sick & tired of it. My PySpark code is ready in my local app but unable to install Java on cloud.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: @aled I have used `image` since it shows both `App output` & `error` side by side. And I have put most of `code` as `code` here in this post.

Comment: You didn't share the errors as text. This is part of [Stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that I mentioned above.

Comment: @aled have updated post with `error` as text

Answer (score 1):

Exception in the screenshot indicates that you do not have rmp package installed on your python environment.

To install this package you should modify you environment file if you are using it by adding this dependency:
`rpm`

or install it with a shell script

```bash
pip install rpm
```

You might also need bindings as well: `python-rpm`

But if you are installing this rpm package using external shell command, maybe you do not need rpm-python package?

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting this `error` because I am already using `import rpm` and I am not sure if I am using any shell command to install rpm.

Comment: `import rpm` is part of your python code. If you do not have this package in your environment, you will not be able to import it into your script.

Comment: yes I agree. I am not sure how to include shell script in `streamlit` but will try to figure out... thanks for helping me out and giving me a direction for further steps.